# Where can I publish small database for free?

Tags: releasing-data, sql

Is there any site where one can easily publish a small database (<5MB)? Ideally, the data should be published in a way that it could be sql selected by number of parameters. Just like any national statistical office (for example, [Sweden](http://www.statistikdatabasen.scb.se/pxweb/en/ssd/START__BE__BE0101__BE0101A/BefolkningNy/?rxid=a2981844-9d8a-428d-a9f7-7360e6b98812)).

Of course, I only need to publish small datasets. But the key feature, it the possibility to select a subset of the data easily.

Comment: What is the data, and whom would be the target audience for using the data?

Comment: I would assume it'd be more likely to find companies willing to host dumps -- allowing SQL queries are more costly (memory, etc.) and riskier (issues of database security).  Unfortunately, WebSQL was removed from the HTML5 standard ... however, [most major browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage), so provided people aren't using Firefox or IE, you can serve static files (database dump + javascript to set up a client-side search interface)

Comment: Hey, I work at OpenDataSoft. We are working on a free offer to publish, explore, visualize and share Open Data. I'm confident it'll be live at the end of september. If you want to beta test it don't hesitate to ping me: nicolas [dot] terpolilli [at] opendatasoft.com

Comment: @Terpo, I knew the feature has to appear soon! I searched through the web with all my might and didn't find anything. Of course, I want to betta-test the feature (ping sent)

Comment: Can you quantify small, i.e. around how many bytes (order of magnitude)?

Comment: @Franck, by small I mean something  less than 5 MB

Comment: @Andrew, there is no specific target auditory, but I have to make the data available even for those who only know how to open an xlsx file

Comment: Google Spreadsheets are easy to use, resemble Excel, and will have all sorts of filtering and export options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's really simple, you can use the [CSV viewer from Github](https://help.github.com/articles/rendering-csv-and-tsv-data/), which has a built-in search tool.

A similar tool is [datapipes](http://datapipes.okfnlabs.org/) and for [HTML](http://datapipes.okfnlabs.org/html/) from OKFN Labs.  [See the demo](http://datapipes.okfnlabs.org/csv/html/?url=https://raw.github.com/datasets/s-and-p-500-companies/master/data/constituents-financials.csv).

---

For a more complicated dataset, with more than one table, then another simple option is to export the database as a .SQL file and then let users import it into the SQL database of their choice. You can host the .sql file anywhere, but Github and Datahub.io are two good choices. Here is a [simple example](http://datahub.io/dataset/omegawiki/resource/92fa903d-cd60-4ff4-a5b7-ed1687ca6360).

I can expand this answer for tips on how to do this if that is the direction you go.

---

Another option is then to use visualization tool or other Javascript library for display CSV data. See for example [D3.js + CSV](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV). There are hosts of other CSV-editors and viewers for the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
My main concern is, data selection (filtering) should be easily available for a person with basic computer skills. Something like a simple data sheet with the ability to filter by each column and easy export to csv and xlsx would do.

Comment: @Ilya - are you planning on hosting the site yourself, or using a free hosting solution (like datahub or github)?

Comment: taking  into account the small amount of my data, I would prefer some ready-made solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for completely out of the box solution, datahubs.io or opendata.socrata.com (*) are your best bets.

With all datasets posted on Socrata, you get an embeddable and filterable view (such as https://opendata.socrata.com/d/iu3z-yanc) in addition to an automatically documented API (such as http://dev.socrata.com/foundry/#/opendata.socrata.com/iu3z-yanc)

** In full disclosure, I work for Socrata*